# Java Script problem with adding and deleting rows

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to add and delete rows dynamically using Java Script keeping in mind a few custom conditions

1) the entire block of HTML which contains 3 rows must be added when we click on add new row

2) the previously entered row should be deleted with the delete button

3) the drop downs should function as desired ( a section of java script code is used for dropdowns which basically is  " if option A is chosen display related options in the next dropdown "

### HTML Code

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<div class="header" align="center">
  <h1>Downtime Report Form</h1>
</div>



  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript  <form class="dt" method="post" id="data1">-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DowntimeForm.css">

<form  method="post">



<table id="data" Width = "100%"  >
<tr>
<td width = "10%">Date and time </td>
<td width = "3%">:</td>
<td width = "17%">    <input type="datetime-local" id="breakdown-time"
         name="breakdown-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
         min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2025-06-14T00:00" required>
</td>



<td width = "10%">Line Number</td>
<td width = "3%">:</td>
<td width = "8%" >   <select id="LineSelection" name="Line Number" required>
           <option value="03">03</option>
           <option value="04">04</option>
           <option value="05">05</option>
           <option value="60">60</option>
           <option value="70">70</option>

</select>
</td>

<td width = "12%" >Operator Name</td>
<td width = "3%">:</td>
<td width = "17%" ><input type="text" name="Operator Name" value="" required id="opname" ></td>




<td width = "11%">Product Type</td>
<td width = "3%">:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Product Type" value="" required id="ptype"> </td>
<td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>


</tr>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<tr class="blank_row">
<td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>


<tr>

<td width = "8%" >Downtime Type</td>
<td width = "3%" >:</td>
<td  width = "10%" > <select class="form-control"  id="firstList" name="firstList" onClick="getdowntimeItem()" required>
 </select> </td>



<td width = "12%">Downtime Subtype</td>
<td width = "3%">:</td>
<td width = "10%"> <select class="form-control"  id="secondList" name="secondList" required>
</select> </td>


<td width = "12%">Downtime Minutes</td>
<td width ="3%">:</td>
<td  width = "10%"><input type="number" name="Downtime Minutes" value="" required id="dmin"> </td>

</tr>




<p> </p>
```

### JavaScript For Dropdowns

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function () {

var list1 = document.getElementById('firstList');

list1.options[0] = new Option('--Select--', '');
list1.options[1] = new Option('Electrical', 'Electrical');
list1.options[2] = new Option('Mechanical', 'Mechanical');
list1.options[3] = new Option('Process', 'Process');
list1.options[4] = new Option('Preventive', 'Preventive');
});

function getdowntimeItem(){
 
            var list1 = document.getElementById('firstList');
            var list2 = document.getElementById("secondList");
            var list1SelectedValue = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;
             
            if (list1SelectedValue=='Electrical')
            {
                 
                list2.options.length=0;
                list2.options[0] = new Option('--Select--', '');
                list2.options[1] = new Option('Power Outage', 'Power Outage');
                list2.options[2] = new Option('Drive Fault', 'Drive Fault');
                list2.options[3] = new Option('Motor Issue', 'Motor Issue');
                list2.options[4] = new Option('Sensor Issue', 'Sensor Issue');
                list2.options[5] = new Option('Operator Issue', 'Operator Issue');
                 
            }
            else if (list1SelectedValue=='Mechanical')
            {
                 
                list2.options.length=0;
                list2.options[0] = new Option('--Select--', '');
                list2.options[1] = new Option('Bearing', 'Bearing');
                list2.options[2] = new Option('Gear Box', 'Gear Box');
                list2.options[3] = new Option('Roller Damage', 'Roller Damage');
                list2.options[4] = new Option('Speed Issue', 'Speed Issue');
                list2.options[5] = new Option('Other', 'Other');
                 
            }
else if (list1SelectedValue=='Process')
{
list2.options.length=0;
list2.options[0] = new Option('--Select--','')
list2.options[1] = new Option('Product Change', 'Product Change');
list2.options[2] = new Option('Change Over', 'Change Over');
list2.options[3] = new Option('Fiber Issue', 'Fiber Issue');
list2.options[4] = new Option('Clogging In M/C', 'Clogging in M/C');
list2.options[5] = new Option('Needling Issue', 'Needling Issue');
list2.options[6] = new Option('Other', 'Other');

}
else if (list1SelectedValue=='Preventive')
{
list2.options.length=0;
list2.options[0] = new Option('--Select--','')
list2.options[1] = new Option('Daily PM', 'Daily PM');
list2.options[2] = new Option('Weekly PM', 'Weekly');

}
}
  </script>
```

### JavaScript for Add Remove

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addRow(data) {

            var data = document.getElementById("data");

            var rowCount = data.rows.length;
            var row = data.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = data.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = data.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
      }}


</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script lang="JavaScript">


        function deleteRow(data) {
                    try {
                    var table = document.getElementById("data");
                    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                        var row = table.rows[i];
                        if(rowCount <= 2) {
                                alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                                break;
                            }
                            table.deleteRow(i);
                            rowCount--;
                            i--;
                        }


                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        alert(e);
                    }}


</script>
```

1. The Problem I'm facing   The add remove button doesn't add the
   entire block of rows.
2. The delete rows doesn't delete the entire block of previous added rows and 
   only deletes one row
3. Also after adding a block of rows using JS function the drop downs for added rows doesn't work I believe this is due to the JS controlling the options of the dropdown.

If someone can provide some help regarding this it would certainly be useful

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but wanted to flag: It's bad practice to put `div` elements anywhere other than inside the `body` tag.

Comment: sean is right, your HTML is atrocious. Please help us help you by [validating your HTML](https://jsonformatter.org/html-validator)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think HTML was the issue I was able to achieve the addition of row chunks through JS script modification basically had to add an extra loop, still stuck with the deletion function though.

Comment: The code is just too bad